# Makes it sense to create an object of a class which extends Service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

Does it make sense to create an object of a class which extends Service?
I mean the following:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(...){
       MyService service = new MyService(...);
       ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Service.java:

```
public class MyService extends Service{
   public MyService(...){
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

I think it does not make sense, because e.g. in my opinion it is not possible to unregister the service. The reason: the service is never started by startService(...).

Does anyone has some hints for me? Thank you!

Comment: no, it doesn't. your service wouldn't be able to do anything. it's context would no be initialized ...

Comment: @njzk2: I think your answer may be incorrect. I created the construct shown above. Into the "service" I implemented an onLocationChangedListener and transfer the location-object to the activity by a BroadcastReceiver. This works. The only thing that is not working is to unregister the service.

Comment: it works because your service is not used as a service. it is used as any object. remove the 'extends Service' part and the behaviour should be identical.

Comment: You wouldn't do `new MyApp()`, `new MyActivity()` or `new MyFragment()`, so yeah, don't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can create an object of a class that extends `Service` but it doesn't make any *programmatic* sense. The fundamental reason to create an object is to use functionalities that class offer. In android paradigm, you would rather `bind` to a service to use its functionalities.